# Do the const and close keywords in Lua actually do anything?

Tags: lua, scope, constants, local-variables

I was excited to learn that, as of Lua 5.4, Lua supports constant (`const`) and to-be-closed (`close`) variables! However, upon testing these keywords, they don't seem to do anything at all. I wrote the following code to sample the features to get a better grasp of their exact usage:

```lua
function f()
  local const x = 3
  print(x)
  x = 2
  print(x)
end

f()

function g()
  local close x = {}
  setmetatable(x, {__close = function() print("closed!") end})
end

g()
```

I titled the file `constCheck.lua` and ran it with `lua constCheck.lua`. The output is as follows:

```
3
2
```

I was expecting an error on my call to `f()`, or at least for it to print `3` twice, instead it seemed to reassign `x` with no issue at all. Further, I was expecting the call to `g()` to print out "closed!" when `x` left scope at the end of the function, but this did not happen. I can't find very many examples of these keywords' usage. Am I using them properly? Do they work?

Note: `lua -v => Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`

Comment: next time, if you want to know how to use a Lua feature properly you best refer to the Lua reference manual. guessing syntax is never a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I'm just not used to how the Lua manual is organized. The only reference to constants in the index is with regards to the C API, and when I searched for "const" in the manual body I got lots of results for "construct", so I tried to narrow my search down by adding a space ("const "), but the only reference to the const keyword is followed by a comma, so I once again primarily got results about the C API. I didn't know that it was a local declaration exclusive feature at the time, and didn't think to check there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is `<const>` not `const`, and `<close>` not `close`

See https://lwn.net/Articles/826134/

```lua
do
  local x <const> = 42
  x = x+1
end
-- ERROR: attempt to assign to const variable 'x'
```

And some example https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/testes/code.lua#L11

> `local k0aux <const> = 0`

https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/testes/files.lua#L128

> `local f <close> = assert(io.open(file, "w"))`

Answer (score 7):

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual : 3.3.7 - Local Declarations](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.7)

> Each variable name may be **postfixed**  by an attribute ( **a name between angle brackets**):
>
> attrib ::= [‘<’ Name ‘>’]
>
> There are two possible attributes: const, which declares a constant
> variable, that is, a variable that cannot be assigned to after its
> initialization; and close, which declares a to-be-closed variable

So you would have to write `local x <const> = 3` for example.

Your code `local const x = 3` is equivalent to

```
local const = nil
x = 3
```

So you're actually creating a local nil value `const` and a global number value `x`.

Comment: I see. This does help to clarify why my code was not a syntax error. It did not occur to me that a local variable could be declared uninitialized, since for globals initialization and declaration do not seem to be distinct concepts.